# openstack swift performance metrics collection API

Tags: python, api, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have an openstack setup with ceilometer (polslter and notifier) installed. I am getting the required metrics like Storaeg_objects_incoming_bytes, storage_objects_size of swift in the metering tab. how ceilometer is getting these metrics.. what are the underlying components of swift which ceilometer api is communicating.. i am writing a python code so that the code would be able to communicate the swift drivers and print the metric...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Swift performance matrix please use [SSbench](https://github.com/swiftstack/ssbench)

[Ceilometer](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Ceilometer) is project for utilization matrix & hence one has to look for the API requests & options it provides.

My suggestion would be to try mailing list & connect with the Ceilometer developers.